# How to convert list of lists into a pytho dataframe : getting typeError

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of lists named `list_values` in this format:

```
list_values[0] =

[
 {'lat': 55.8313729, 'lng': -3.9775758},
 {'quality_id': 7, 'quality_tx': 'Intersection'},
 [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '7 Dovecote Road',
   'short_name': '7 Dovecote Rd',
   'types': ['rca_address_line_1']},
   {'long_name': '7', 'short_name': '7', 'types': ['street_number']},
   {'long_name': 'Dovecote Road',
     'short_name': 'Dovecote Rd',
     'types': ['route']}],
   'formatted_address': '7 Dovecote Rd, Motherwell ML1, UK',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 55.8313729, 'lng': -3.9775758},
     'location_type': 'RANGE_INTERPOLATED',
     'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 55.8327218802915,
       'lng': -3.976226819708498},
       'southwest': {'lat': 55.8300239197085, 'lng': -3.978924780291502}}},
   'partial_match': True,
   'types': ['street_address'],
   'rca_extended_properties': {'geocode': {'quality_id': 7,
     'quality_tx': 'Intersection'},
     'distanceInMeters': None,
     'displayCity_tx': 'Motherwell',
     'displayCityNameOrigin_id': 8,
     'searchParcels': False}}]
]
```

Which I would like to convert to a dataframe, where each of the 3 columns will have each of the lists.
But when I try
`lat = pd.DataFrame(list_values)` , I get an error
`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

What would be a good approach to overcome this?

Comment: Your Sample has some errors. Please provide a true sample.

Comment: The true sample has over 50k rows, and I'm assuming the error is stemming from null values or blanks in the lists? Not sure how to find where exactly the errors are

Comment: What @keramat means is that your `list_values` is missing a `}` so the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: sorry, just edited the sample

Comment: No `}` is missing at penultimate line.

Comment: ugh, apologies. uploaded a new one, this should be correctly parenthesized

Comment: @Aamash Haroon, I recommend you to loop over the df creation, until it gives you the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the structure that would work in this particular example:

```
[  
    {'lat': 51.4900961, 'lng': -0.1792465},
    {'quality_id': 9, 'quality_tx': 'Premises'},
    {'address_components': [
        {'long_name': '34 Cranley Gardens','short_name': '34 Cranley Gardens','types': ['rca_address_line_1']},
        {'long_name': 'England','displayCityNameOrigin_id': 8,'searchParcels': False},
        {'reverse_geocode': {'adminLevel3_id': 61719,'cbd_fg': False,'neighborhood_display_city_name_fg': False}}
    ]}
]
```

Comparing this to the code you posted, i found two issues:

1. Right in front of `'address components'`  you are opening a list but
   directly afterwards assign a value in a dictionary type of way by
   using the '`:`'.
2. Further, right in front of `'reverse_geocode'` there is no opening
   '`{`' in your code in order to create a dictionary that consists of
   the key '`reverse_geocode`'  and the following dictionary.

Comment: You're right, there are nested dictionaries in the data. this is what the api returns, that I need to then convert to a dataframe. I have corrected the sample to better represent what it would look like, but it seems like the nonetype error persists

Comment: First of all, the code does not give an Nonetype Error for me, but a AttributeError if i try it. Second, the problem is in that case that you are not passing a list of purely nested dictionaries. There is a list object starting right before 'address_components', as mentioned above.